# Color does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, colors, colordialog

```
if(colorSel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string menucolor = colorSel.Color.Name;
                panel1.BackColor = Color.menucolor;
            }
```

Error: 'Color' Does not contain a definition for 'menucolor'

Answer (score -1):

No worries, i found a solution.

used

```
Color.FromName(menucolor);
```

instead of

```
Color.menucolor
```

Comment: i wanted an RGB color, not a known color, so i actually changed FromName(); to FromArgb(); and ColorSel.Color.toArgb(); works perfectly now.

Comment: Sure. That was __not__ my question! The code still seems 100% nonsense.